# Set SSH idle timeout Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ssh, sshd

I want **incoming** ssh-sessions to automatically disconnect upon inactivity for a security-critical server.

I've set the following settings

```
TCPKeepAlive no
ClientAliveInterval  30
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

I would expect sshd not to send KeepAlive-Packages due to `TCPKeepAlive` and `ClientAliveCountMax` - and my sessions to timeout after 30 seconds. On top of that I think `TCPKeepAlive` could be left at its default which should be `yes`.

I've checked existing sessions like that:

```
root@<server>:/etc/apache2# w
 06:53:51 up 2 days, 21:25,  2 users,  load average: 0,00, 0,00, 0,00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
_____-ad pts/0    ____________      Do11    6.00s  0.99s  0.00s sshd: _____-admin [priv]
_____-us pts/1    ____________     06:40   13:26   0.02s  0.02s -bash
```

The sessions won't timeout...

I restarted sshd of course.

```
root@<server>:/etc/apache2# sshd -T | grep -i "ClientAlive"
clientaliveinterval 30
clientalivecountmax 0
```

Could the client still be sending KeepAlive-Packages? I cannot control all versions of clients that connect..

References:
https://www.golinuxcloud.com/disconnect-idle-ssh-session-tcpkeepaliv-linux/
https://secscan.acron.pl/centos7/5/2/13

EDIT: `TCPKeepAlive yes` doesn't change the behaviour, sessions still linger. I also started a new session after I restarted sshd to avoid having old settings in my ssh-session.

EDIT2: Added keyword "incoming" to the description above to make it clearer, that I want my ssh server (sshd) to drop connections after an idle timeout, because users might forget about their open (and unsed) ssh sessions.

EDIT3: Just for information - used sshd version:

```
root@<server>:/etc/apache2# dpkg -l openssh-server
Gewünscht=Unbekannt/Installieren/R=Entfernen/P=Vollständig Löschen/Halten
| Status=Nicht/Installiert/Config/U=Entpackt/halb konFiguriert/
         Halb installiert/Trigger erWartet/Trigger anhängig
|/ Fehler?=(kein)/R=Neuinstallation notwendig (Status, Fehler: GROSS=schlecht)
||/ Name           Version            Architektur  Beschreibung
+++-==============-==================-============-=================================================================
ii  openssh-server 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.1 amd64        secure shell (SSH) server, for secure access from remote machines
root@<server>:/etc/apache2# sshd -V
unknown option -- V
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

Working as expected in

- Debian 10 (OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019)*
- Ubuntu 16.04 (OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016)

*For Debian 10 I wanted to compare `sshd -T`.
Options that differ: `casignaturealgorithms`, `gssapikexalgorithms`, `hostbasedacceptedkeytypes`, `hostkeyalgorithms`, `kexalgorithms`, `passwordauthentication`, `permitrootlogin`, `pubkeyacceptedkeytypes`, `pubkeyauthoptions`, `securitykeyprovider`

I've only set `passwordauthentication no`

I've connected from the same host, the only difference is I used pubkey authentication for the server in question and password authentication for the Debian 10 server.

Sorry that it's getting long.. It kinda turns into a bug report..

On Debian 10:

- `ClientAliveInterval 10`, `ClientAliveCountMax 3`: `ssh -v` records the message `debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1` every 10 seconds
- `ClientAliveInterval 10`, `ClientAliveCountMax 0`: session disconnects after 10 seconds.

On Ubuntu 20.04:

- `ClientAliveInterval 10`, `ClientAliveCountMax 0`: `ssh -v` records the message `debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1` every 10 seconds

Comment: You do restart ssh after the alterations? :) Cuz what you do here is correct.

Comment: I didn't restart ```ssh```, but ```sshd```. That ```sshd``` sees the correct settings I also verified with ```sshd -T```. I even did ```systemctl stop sshd; netstat -tulpen``` and it showed nothing listening on port 22, so I started sshd again. But the behaviour is unchanged. I'll add the sshd version to the post and check the behaviour on other servers (Ubuntu 16.04/18.04, SLES)... I doubt it's a bug though

Comment: I observe a difference in the man page for sshd_config between Ubuntu server 16.04 and 20.04: under ClientAliveCountMax 16.04 does not have this part `Setting a zero ClientAliveCountMax disables connection termination.` I have repeated all of your work and got the same results. With tcpdump, I observe a packet sent to and a reply from the client no matter the settings.

Comment: interesting [related reading](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=254707), particularly [post #10](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1898663#p1898663).

Comment: see also [here](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3182). And [here](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3172)

Comment: You're really an ssh expert Doug! Thanks for your time and effort! I'll give TMOUT a shot then =) Since your comment answers the question, do you want to write an answer? I'll gladly accept it =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of the more recent versions of openssh server, there is no way to configure an inactivity/idle timeout via `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

While one can find a great many references saying to set `ClientAliveCountMax 0` in conjunction with `ClientAliveInterval N` to create an inactivity/idle timeout, evidently that was not an intended ability and has now been intentionally closed.

The relevant change to [the sshd_config man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/sshd_config.5.html) for ClientAliveCountMax is this additional sentence: "`Setting a zero ClientAliveCountMax disables connection termination.`"

Some have submitted bug reports against openssh, in particular [this one](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3182) and [this one](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3172). Some particularly relevant excerpts:

> ClientAliveCountMax=0 has never been specified to work as an idle
> timeout. If it did that then it was by accident and would be
> unreliable. E.g. if the client specified it's own ServerAliveTimeout
> or kept a forwarded TCP connection open then it would never fire.

and

> If you need a idle timeout, then I suggest looking at shell features
> (e.g. bash's TMOUT) or something like a PAM module.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer that may work for all logins, including SSH.
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

from the console: sudo nano (or whichever editor is loaded) /etc/profile

add the line:

TMOUT=300

or whatever length of time you desire in seconds. I rebooted after the change.

I found the info here: https://linuxhandbook.com/auto-logout-linux/
and included a section for SSH only but didn't seem to work for SSH when I tried it.
Since this server is used headless, that is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Like another answer here says, the key to a modern SSH connection inactivity timeout is `TMOUT=X`, where X is a number of seconds > 0.

I only wanted this for my user account, not every user on the system, so I added the following in my `~/.bashrc` file instead of `/etc/profile`:

```
# Timout my SSH connection after 5 minutes
export TMOUT=300
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT
```