# SSH server timeout - one user (mine) is not timing out

Tags: server, ssh

So I recently enabled a timeout on my Ubuntu 18.04.6 SSH server. It seems to be kicking everyone off once the idle timeout hits which is great. However it is not working for me. My connection will stay active no matter what. Not sure why? This causes an issue once my KRB5 ticket expires and floods my syslog with events. Just in case it's asked, this is how I enabled the timeout. I have this in my sshd_config

`ClientAliveInterval 120m`
`ClientAliveCountMax 0`

Comment: We need to know your version of Ubuntu, as how this works has [changed in recent versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265201/set-ssh-idle-timeout-ubuntu-20-04/1265510#1265510).

Comment: It is a good practice to include your Ubuntu version number [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1399720/edit).

Comment: Edited post to include the version of Ubuntu.